# Package appears upgradeable but cannot upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I have a package that gets listed as upgradeable but doesn't get upgraded when issuing `apt upgrade`

like this:

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
dotnet-runtime-2.0.0/xenial 2.0.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.0-1]
dotnet-runtime-2.0.0/zesty,now 2.0.0-1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.0.0-1]    

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ dpkg -s dotnet-runtime-2.0.0
Package: dotnet-runtime-2.0.0
Status: install ok installed
[...]
Version: 2.0.0-1
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing should happen since this:

```
dotnet-runtime-2.0.0/xenial 2.0.0-1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.0.0-1]
dotnet-runtime-2.0.0/zesty,now 2.0.0-1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.0.0-1]
```

two lines are both saying: `2.0.0-1`, run `sudo apt update` to update your package index.

Comment: I did so, I got a `1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.` message and still got the same issue